# Is it possible to use ggpredict() for more than four terms?

Tags: r, predict

I'm trying to predict marginal values with ggpredict(). It works fine if we are intressted in less than 4 terms. However, if we want marginal predictions for 5 variables, we get the following error message:

> "`terms` must have not more than four values. Using first four values
> now."

Is there any option to use more than 4 values?

My model is

```
mod <- lmer(Y ~ time + gender + BMI_cat + smoking+ illness stage + time:gender + time:BMI_cat +  time:smoking + (time|ID))
```

After fitting the model I used:

```
ggpredict(mod, terms = c("time[0:25]", "gender", "smoking", "illness stage", "BMI_cat"))
```

Thank you.